# How to customize output of plugin

Tags: theme-development

I'm developing my own theme for WordPress and I need plugin to fit into it (styles, layout), but I'm pretty new to PHP and can't make this work.

So, code from plugin looks like:

```
function bbpress_hook_get()
{
    echo '<h2 class="bbpas-h2">' . wp_kses_post( $this->parent->option['before_forum_display'] ) . "</h2>" 
    . $this->shortcode_activity() 
    . wp_kses_post( $this->parent->option['after_forum_display'] ) ;
}
```

And this is what I came up with in `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('bbpress_hook_get', 'statistics');
function statistics()
{
    echo '<h2 class="bbpas-h2">' . wp_kses_post( $this->parent->option['before_forum_display'] ) . "</h2>" 
    . $this->shortcode_activity() 
    . wp_kses_post( $this->parent->option['after_forum_display'] ) ;
}
```

And of course it doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: it doest work in what way? please point out what you want and what you are actually getting.

Comment: oh, sorry, in this example i want to replace '<h2 class="bbpas-h2">' and '</h2> to lets say '<div class="font_1' and '</div>'